# What is the best solution: How to combine 2 buttons in one - may be with js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to make my checkout page more friendly and how to do this:

I have guest form`s and save button after them. And after guest info is saved (instead payment option) are show send my order button - this is from one module Cash on delivery, but instead to choice only this i move button to be showed directly.

BUT: Many clients are confused from this "save" button. I want to marge this two buttons in one.

How to do this? What is the best solution: to add some js when for save button or adding new button instead these 2?

You can see the problem page in my live shop here: http://bijutaniki.com/porychka (do not forget to add product like: http://bijutaniki.com/prysteni/8-prysten-na-nastroenieto.html - and shop is on bulgarian)

Now process looks like that:
[image]
[image]

What i want to do:
[image]

I try two times to add new button with js instead these to but without success. May be if use "save" button and add js to click on other "send order" button will be more easy because when "save" been clicked check fields above and if fields are valid show message.

What are you think, how to combine this buttons.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Save button and message:

```
{$HOOK_CREATE_ACCOUNT_FORM}
<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" class="exclusive button" name="submitGuestAccount" id="submitGuestAccount" value="{l s='Save'}" />
</p>
<p style="display: none;" id="opc_account_saved">
{l s='Account information saved successfully'}
</p>
<p class="required opc-required" style="clear: both;">
</p>
```

Send order button (with smile):

```
<div class="cod_cofirm">
<form action="{$link->getModuleLink('cashondelivery', 'validation', [], true)|escape:'html'}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="1" />
<p class="cart_navigation" id="cart_navigation">
<input type="submit" value="{l s='Send order' mod='cashondelivery'}" class="extraorderbutton" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
```

Because prestashop have controllers may be need to show code from some controller?

Comment: Happen to have a [JS Fiddle that we can play with?](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: What have you tried? Doesn't seem like doing so adds any real business value for your site, but of course it is possible with JavaScript but you can't just ask for code here you need to show what you are stuck with other than a concept.

Comment: I think you should make some button like
Save and Send order or just call it send order user dont care i quess.
Then u can save it by ajax after success send order.

Comment: jamcoope, Thanks for reply. Many of my clients have problems with checkout. Seems very clean and simple for me but least one at day ask me in chat or on phone: How to order - other think they orders for send with clicking on "save button"... E commerce is strange business. Every day you talking with dummies and want to get they money. :)
@Dox, I try to add new button but save button check form if valid, invalid and in prestashop  need first to save user data then order. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no valid answer without showing us code, I'll try it anyway:

```
$('NEW_Send_Order_btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('Save_btn').trigger('click');
  if($('Save_btn').hasClass('well_done')){
    $('Send_my_order').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Comment: I try something like this before month or two but have problems with errors because "save" button shows errors if forms are not valid.
I edit post and add part from code - full code is in several .tpl and controller .php files.

Thanks for suggestion!